# Diferentes estratégias de regex para obter o mesmo resultado

Tags: java, regex, desempenho

Eu tenho o seguinte input:

```
Detalhamento de Serviços nº: 999-99999-9999
```

Eu preciso obter o número em um grupo, pra isso eu utilizaria:

```
Detalhamento de Serviços nº: (\d+-\d+-\d+)
```

Porém eu não posso confiar se vai haver ou não a string `nº:`(OBS: não o número de telefone, e sim essa string mesmo). Então eu teria 2 opções:

```
 1. Detalhamento de Serviços.+(\d+-\d+-\d+) 
 2. Detalhamento de Serviços[\D]+(\d+-\d+-\d+)
```

Ambos regex iriam retornar o mesmo resultado, a dúvida é:

Qual a diferença entre utilizar a classe "any character" e "non-digit" nesse caso? Qual a melhor prática e porque? Qual tem maior performance e porque?

Comment: Levando em conta apenas o nome, "any character" é literalmente qualquer caractere, ao passo que "non-digit" é qualquer caractere exceto números, não? Logo, eles não são a mesma coisa.

Comment: Sim, porém para procurar pelo input que coloquei como exemplo, ambos servem e retornam o resultado desejado. A questão é: qual é o correto pra se usar e pq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade, as duas regex que você indicou não retornam o mesmo resultado. Fiz um teste no **JDK 1.7.0_80**, e também é possível vê-las funcionando (de maneira diferente) [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/IncOSL/1) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/Lukfy3/1/).

Eu criei um método bem simples, para testar uma regex:

```
public void testregex(String input, String regex) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Em seguida, testei a mesma entrada usando as duas regex (detalhe que o `\` deve ser escapado, por isso é escrito como `\\`):

```
String input = "Detalhamento de Serviços nº: 999-99999-9999";
testregex(input, "Detalhamento de Serviços.+(\\d+-\\d+-\\d+)");
testregex(input, "Detalhamento de Serviços\\D+(\\d+-\\d+-\\d+)");
```

O resultado foi:

```
9-99999-9999
999-99999-9999
```

Isso acontece porque os quantificadores `+` e `*` [são "gananciosos"](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) e tentam pegar o máximo possível de caracteres. No primeiro caso, ele também pega os dois primeiros dígitos `9`, porque o restante da `String` (`9-99999-9999`) também satisfaz a última parte da regex (`\d+-\d+-\d+`).

No segundo caso, ele não pega os dois primeiros `9` porque `\D` garante que não vai pegar dígitos.

Sendo assim, algumas soluções possíveis são:

- Usar o `\D`: assim, você garante que, por mais que o quantificador seja ganancioso, ele não vai pegar um dígito por engano
- Usar um `?` logo após o quantificador `+`, pois isso [cancela o comportamento "ganancioso"](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution). A regex fica assim: `Detalhamento de Serviços.+?(\d+-\d+-\d+)` - note o uso de `.+?` para remover a "ganância"
- Definir a quantidade de dígitos, usando `{}`. Por exemplo, se a quantidade de dígitos é sempre "3-5-4", você pode usar `Detalhamento de Serviços.+?(\d{3}-\d{5}-\d{4})`. Se a quantidade de dígitos varia, use a sintaxe `{min,max}`. Por exemplo, se há um mínimo de 2 dígitos e máximo de 3, use `{2,3}` (e use o "cancelador de ganância", ou o `\D` para garantir). Adapte de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Comment: Opa, perfeito. Eu não tinha prestado atenção no retorno pelo matcher.group, eu apenas havia utilizado o matcher.find pra retornar se havia achado ou não.